# php- error sorting array with time stamps as values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This might be a simple one but i have been struggling to get the output sorted correctly for an array. 
I want to sort the following array by the date time values in ascending order.

```
Array ( 
[2] => 
[5] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-10-08 08:30:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata ) 
[6] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-12-01 01:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata ) 
[4] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-12-31 11:30:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata ) 
[3] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-12-04 13:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata ) 
[1] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-12-30 07:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata ) 
[0] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-12-01 02:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata ) 
 )
```

I have tried `uasort` as below but it did not provide the correct sorting. Did anyone faced this issue earlier?

`uasort($item_date_converted, function ($a, $b) { return $a - $b; });`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

DateTime objects can be compared using standard comparison operators. So if you want to use `uasort`, you just need to alter your comparison function so that it returns the expected value. The PHP [documentation of `uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) refers you to the [documentation of `usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for explanation of user-defined comparison functions, which says:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

So your `uasort` can be done like this:

```
uasort($item_date_converted, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a < $b) return -1;
    if ($a > $b) return 1;
    return 0;        
});
```

This can be further simplified by using `asort` rather than `uasort`. If this is just an array of DateTime objects, it can be sorted without a user function. It is this simple:

```
asort($item_date_converted);
```

Comment: I have tried asort and it worked in a very simple manner, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [diff()](http://php.net/manual/ro/datetime.diff.php) function on the DateTime objects:

```
uasort($item_date_converted, function ($a, $b) { return $a->diff($b)->days; });
```

Or you can sort by the corresponding [timestamps](http://php.net/manual/ro/datetime.gettimestamp.php):

```
uasort($item_date_converted, function ($a, $b) { return $a->getTimestamp() - $b->getTimestamp(); });
```